# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on class attribut declaration

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
class ClassData {
  name: string;
  interfaces: string[] = [];
  superclass: string;
  members: any = {};
}
```

Sorry to ask but I'm stuck:
what did I do wrong?
I use node v14.17.0

I have this error:

```
 name: string;
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are writing TypeScript here.
Node and JavaScript does not have types at all.

take a look at [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html) when you are used to write types.

EDIT:
Node.js and JavaScript interpret your example as failure because it does not understand what `prop: string` means.
If you want your IDE to give you some autocomplete and type information you can specify some stuff in a doc comment like so:

```js
class Rectangle {
  /**
   * @param {number} height 
   * @param {number} width 
   */
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
  area() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
};
```

Works in most IDEs.

Comment: I don't get it, I see stuff like : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class

I just want my IDE suggest me field to fill.